# find the minimum size dominating set for a tree using greedy algorithm

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Dominating Set (DS) := given an undirected graph G = (V;E), a set of
vertices S  V is a dominating set if for every vertex in V , there is a vertex in
S that is adjacent to v. Entire vertex set V is a trivial dominating set in
any graph.

Find minimum size dominating set for a tree.

Comment: I think the rule is sort of clear: pick the parent of two nodes. for two subtree, pick the root node of that subtree.

Comment: faint. find the minimum size dominating set for a tree, using greedy.

Comment: So basically, find the minimum amount of points that touch all other points in the graph

Comment: Considering you had a homework problem of similar nature, I find it hard to believe this is an interview question. :-(

Comment: What does a "a set of vertices S V" and "for every v 2 V" mean? I have nothing against homework questions as long as 1. you aren't outright lying about it and 2. you bother to actually write a meaningful problem statement. -1.

Comment: @glowcoder, many interview questions are exactly homework problems such as longest palindrome subsequence, maximum consecutive subsequence, maximum profit of list jobs, and etc. The reason I tag it as an interview question because it is asked by one of my classmate in the interview

Comment: This certainly reads like a homework problem.

Comment: @IVlad, can you please explain a little bit about it?

Comment: I just delete the "interview-questions" tag to ...

Answer (score 4):

I'll attempt to prove this in a more formal way.

**OUTLINE**

To prove your greedy algorithm is correct, you need to prove two things:

1. First, that your greedy choice is valid and can always be used in the formation of an optimal solution, and
2. second, that your problem has an optimal substructure property, that is, you can form an optimal solution from optimal solutions to subproblems of your own problem.

**Greedy Choice**: In your tree T = (V, E), find a vertex *v* in the tree with the highest number of leaves. Add it to your dominant set.

**Optimal Substructure**

T' = (V', E') such that:

- V' = V \ ({a : a ϵ V, a is adjacent to v, and a's degree ≤ 2} ∪ {v})
- E' = E - any edge involving any of the removed vertices

**In other words**

Look for a vertex with the highest number of leaves, remove any of its adjacent vertices with degree less than or equal to 2, then remove v itself, and add it to your dominant set. Repeat this until you have no vertices left.

---

**PROOF**

**Greedy choice proof**

For any leaf *l*, it must be that either itself or its parent is in the dominant set. In our case, the vertex *v* we would have chosen is in this situation.

Let *A* = {*v<sub>1</sub> , v<sub>2</sub> , ... , v<sub>k</sub>*} be a minimum dominant set of T. If A already has *v* as member, we are done. If it does not, we see two situations:

1. *v* has some neighbouring leaf *l*. Then,  *l* must be part of the dominant set, otherwise our set is not dominating the entire tree. We can simply thus form *A'* = {*A* - *{l}* + {*v*}} and still be a dominant set. Since |*A'*| = |*A*|, *A'* is still optimal.
2. *v* does not have any neighbouring leaves *l*. Then, because *v* was chosen such that it has the highest number of leaves, then no vertex in *T* have any leaves. Then *T* is not a tree. Contradiction.

Thus, we will always be able to form an optimal solution with our greedy choice.

**Optimal Substructure proof**

Suppose that *A* is a minimum dominant set for *T* = (*V, E*), but that *A'* = *A* \ {*v*} is not a minimum dominant set for *T'* as defined above.

Make a minimum dominant set for T', call it B. As aforementioned, |*B*| < |*A'*|. It can be shown that *B'* = *B* ∪ {*v*} is a dominating set for *T*. Then, since |*A'*| = |*A*| - 1, |*B'*| = |*B*| + 1, we get |*B'*| < |*A*|. This is contradictory, since we assumed that *A* is an minimum independent set. Thus it must be that *A'* is also a minimum independent set of *T'*.

Proving *B'* = *B* ∪ {*v*} is a dominating set for *T*:

- *v* may have had adjacent vertices adjacent not in *T'*. We will show that any vertices that were not considered in *T'* will be dominated by vertices in *B'* (This means that we picked our set optimally): Let *y* be some vertex adjacent to *v* and not in *T'*. By definition of *T'*, y can only have degree 1 or 2. Now, *y* is dominated by *v*. If *y* is a leaf, then we are done. However, if *y* is of degree 2, then *y* is connected another node which is necessarily in the dominant set of *B*. This is because, when we removed *v* to make T', the degree of *y* became 1, meaning that *y* or its parent was necessarily added to the dominant set. Hence, *B'* is a dominant set for *T*.

Answer (score 2):

1- Always start from leafs

2- Add their parent to DS and cut the children

3- Mark parent's of selected parent as already dominated

4- After completing process , check whether those marked nodes has a children that is not
dominated and add them to DS

Good luck

Comment: linear time O(V) algorithm? don't you need to sort the nodes first?

Comment: no need to sort at all, yes it is linear time in O(|V|+|E|), you should not consider cost of moving between nodes in Time complexity , just number of comparisons.